# I need to access OneDrive for business file through a CMD entry to unpack something

Tags: cmd.exe, eclipse, onedrive

This is the file path that I am trying to access: (yes names have been replaced)

```
C:\Users\MyNAme\OneDrive – company name\MyName\Eclipse\red-app-sdk-3.0-19.12\webmodules\tools\offline-bundle
```

The command prompt does not seem  to like the `OneDrive - company name`. I have also tried `%onedrive%` as well and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Use quotes...Provide the exact command you used.  Use placeholders if you want.

Comment: How far along the path can you get in cmd? Are the files offline?

Comment: answer is, cd "copy name of the one drive as it is"

Answer (score 5):

I can verify that @Ramhound is correct. You need to put quotes around the variable because when it expands the resultant string includes spaces which are interpreted as they are by the command interpreter.

This does not work:

```
dir %OneDrive%
```

This does:

```
dir "%OneDrive%"
```

Comment: For anyone else using this, it's worth noting that there may be more environment variables.  %OneDrive%,%OneDriveCommercial%, and %OneDriveConsumer%.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625628/4689766